# transform Sync Mode set to sync Rigidbody 3d but no rigidbody component found

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

As the title say, i have this error. I have just started with multiplayer setting up.

Here are images of my settings on player prefab:
[image]

And here is network manager:

[image]

Error image:
[image]

Comment: Can you also show the script? @AleksaRistic

Comment: Of course but tell me what script

Comment: What is causing the error? Maybe picture of the error can help. Rn all i can say is wildy guessing, you showed the **Lightswordman**  but in your network manager as player prefab you have **Player**

Comment: Lightswordman was name of gameobject inside scene but when i set it to prefab i changed it's name to Player so image was outdated for few seconds but i uploaded new one and added error image now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - Prefab was checked as inactive so it couldn't find rigidboy.